# Terraform S3 Notification for multiple suffix's

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 1 S3 bucket and want to trigger the same lambda for two different types of object:create scenarios.

I tried to have multiple `aws_s3_bucket_notification` blocks, but only one was made, terraform Notes:

`S3 Buckets only support a single notification configuration. Declaring multiple aws_s3_bucket_notification resources to the same S3 Bucket will cause a perpetual difference in configuration. See the example "Trigger multiple Lambda functions" for an option.`

I tried doing an `OR` statement, but TF didnt like that either

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket     = var.my_bucket_id
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.lambda_perm]

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "my functions arn"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "content/"
    filter_suffix       = "-webpage.html" || "-image.png"
  }
}
```

Need help having a suffix string that looks for two different strings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need **multiple** `lambda_function` blocks:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket     = var.my_bucket_id
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.lambda_perm]

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "my functions arn"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "content/"
    filter_suffix       = "-webpage.html"
  }

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "my functions arn"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "content/"
    filter_suffix       = "-image.png"
  }

}
```